# When creating a bulletin board, I'm asking how to set the id and post number primary keys

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making a bulletin board. But when I created the bulletin board, I assigned a primary key to the id value. But now I want to make a board number. I can't specify the primary key for no because I've already specified the primary key for the id value in the past. I heard that no should be made as a primary key. What should I do in this case?

Comment: unclear. Why no[t] use the primary key id as the board number. Be specific about the SQL you are using. Be clear if `no` something specific or an English word

Comment: i don't know it exectly, but i thought when i make No, i have to make No primarly key, and auto increment, but i already make id primary key, so i can't make no unique and AI and not null, now i can't make no.